# Existence of non-zero continuous function making a family of integrals take the value 0

Tags: integration, functions, improper-integrals

Does there exist any non-zero continuous $f(\lambda): [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any positive real $z$ the following integral is well defined and we have $$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\lambda z}f(\lambda) \ d\lambda = 0$$

I think the answer is no, although continuous functions can get very weird so I am not sure and I can't seem to prove it either way.

Comment: By a simple change of variables you can see that your integral can become $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\mathcal{L}(f(t))$ which does equal 0 when $f(t)=0$

Comment: I haven't seen a proof of uniqueness for Laplace transforms yet so although this does settle the question I would appreciate some more detailed explanation for it.

Comment: The usual result for injectivity of Laplace transform assumes the function $f$ is of exponential order, i.e. there is a constant $c$ such that $|f(\lambda)| \le e^{c\lambda}$ for all $\lambda$.  You don't seem to be assuming that.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a proof that works for $f \in L^2(0,\infty)$ using analyticity and Plancherel's theorem.